# Function on "figure eight" which is not a diffeomorphism due to its topology

Tags: manifolds, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

In my lecture, we've considered $G(x)=F(g(x))$ the "figure eight", where $F(x) = (2\cos(x-\frac{1}{2}\pi), \sin(2(x-\frac{1}{2}\pi))$ and $g(x)=\pi+2\arctan(x)$. 
I understand that this is an example for a bijective immersion which is not a homeomorphism since the figure eight and $\mathbb{R}$ are not homeomorphic. 
Now, I should give an example of a function which maps from figure eight to figure eight bijectivly and homeomorphically, but is not a diffeomorphism due to its topology. 
My idea was to consider the reflection of the figure eight (let's call $G(\mathbb{R}))=A$) an the x-axis, i.e. $R:A\rightarrow A, R(x,y)=(x,-y)$. Intuitively, I thought that this could work since we are able to approach $0$ in A with a sequence $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}\subset \mathbb{R}$ s.t. $x_n \rightarrow 0$ but also with $x_n \rightarrow \pm \infty$.
Is my idea correct and if yes, could you help me proving this?
Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by a diffeomorphism if the domain/range is not a smooth manifold?

Comment: My exercise says: "diffeomorphism of $A$" and that the topology and $C^\infty$ structure on $A$ should be given by $G$. As you're pointing out $A$ is not a smooth manifold, so I think we cannot understand the diffeomorphism in terms of coordinate charts.

Comment: I know one definition of a diffeomorphism in this situation but I do not know what your instructor has in mind. And your example will be a diffeomorphism with the definition I know.

Comment: So, you're suggesting I should ask my instructor at first, what precisely is meant with a diffeomorphism in this situation? Would my example work under the definition you have in mind though?

Comment: You should ask, otherwise how can you solve a problem if you do not know what it is asking for?